# Comparing two tables using sub query ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, case, where-clause

I  can compare two tables for missing data using the below query

```
 SELECT S.DEVID,S.INPUTID,S.PRI,S.CCID FROM [DEVICE-SECURITY].DBO.DEVICE_LINK S
  WHERE HID = 4 
  EXCEPT 
  SELECT  T.DEVID,T.INPUTID,T.PRI,T.CCID  FROM  DEVICE-CONFIG.DBO.DEVICE_LINK T
  WHERE HID = 1
```

> The above query returns four rows which are not present in my source
>   table

Now  i am trying to use a subquery to achieve the same result

```
 SELECT  S.DEVID,S.INPUTID,S.PRI,S.CCID , 
 CASE WHEN S.HID = '4' THEN '1'  END AS HID 
 FROM  [DEVICE-SECURITY].DBO.DEVICE_LINK S
  WHERE S.HID= 4 AND  NOT EXISTS    (
 SELECT T.DEVID,T.INPUTID,T.PRI,T.CCID FROM DEVICE-CONFIG.DBO.DEVICE_LINK  T
   WHERE T.HID = 1 )
```

> It returns no rows .

How to achieve the same result using subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options

You can do a not in filter and then the subquery does not have to connect to the outer

```
SELECT S.DEVID,S.INPUTID,S.PRI,S.CCID , CASE WHEN S.HID = '4' THEN '1' END AS HID FROM [DEVICE-SECURITY].DBO.DEVICE_LINK S WHERE S.HID= 4 AND  S.DEVID+S.INPUTID+S.PRI+S.CCID NOT in ( SELECT T.DEVID+T.INPUTID+T.PRI+T.CCID FROM DEVICE-CONFIG.DBO.DEVICE_LINK T WHERE T.HID = 1 )
```

Or you can keep your not exist and connect the subquery to the main by all your fields you want to compare

```
SELECT S.DEVID,S.INPUTID,S.PRI,S.CCID , CASE WHEN S.HID = '4' THEN '1' END AS HID FROM [DEVICE-SECURITY].DBO.DEVICE_LINK S WHERE S.HID= 4 AND  NOT exists ( SELECT 1 FROM DEVICE-CONFIG.DBO.DEVICE_LINK T WHERE T.HID = 1  and T.DEVID+T.INPUTID+T.PRI+T.CCID=S.DEVID+S.INPUTID+S.PRI+S.CCID)
```

Comment: The point is when you say not exist then if the inner SQL returns something obviously it exists unless you join to the main then it does not exist because it's filtered

Comment: btw, its returing the result

Comment: Great I'm happy to help you

Comment: I didnt get the concatenation part in your query

Comment: does it has same logic of binding matching column

Comment: I did the same as @fuzzytree ,just instead of comparing each column I concatenated.  By an exist it's better to do it without concatenation because it will not use the index properly but if you do an in you have no choice but to concatanate

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent not exists query is

```
SELECT S.DEVID,S.INPUTID,S.PRI,S.CCID FROM [DEVICE-SECURITY].DBO.DEVICE_LINK S
  WHERE HID = 4 
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM  DEVICE-CONFIG.DBO.DEVICE_LINK T
    WHERE HID = 1 
    AND T.DEVID = S.DEVID AND T.INPUTID = S.INPUTID
    AND T.PRI = S.PRI AND T.CCID = S.CCID
)
```

Comment: Its fine and returning

Comment: is it necessary to bind columns in exists statements

Comment: it depends on what you're checking the existence for, but yes usually you do bind at least one column in an exists subquery. if you want to simulate `except` then you should all bind all columns in the `select` of the `except` query